# How can you throttle a long-running command-line EXE to avoid pegging the CPU?

Tags: c#

I have a command line EXE written in C#.  It's log parser that grinds through several GB worth of log files every night.

It pegs the processor at 100% for quite a while.  Not ideal.

How could I "throttle" the app?  It can take as long as it wants, but I'd rather have it use less of the total CPU.

Is there some coding method or theory to make an EXE slow down and take less CPU?  I can't do anything in the environment it runs (like change the process priority), so any changes have to be within the code of the app itself.

Comment: Idle CPU is the devil's plaything!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the priority of the threads using the [`Thread.Priority`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx) property.

Of course, if there's nothing else trying to run that will still use 100% CPU - but I guess in that case you don't mind so much.

Does your application create any other threads or use the thread pool? If it does, you'll probably want to make sure those threads have a reduced priority too.

EDIT: Setting the process's overall priority is probably a better solution in general, but I'll leave this one up as an alternative.

Comment: This would be my normal approach in most situations... Even though I posted a different alternative, and now added use cases.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process myProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
myProc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;
```

If that isn't low enough, there is a `ProcessPriorityClass.Idle`

[MSDN Link 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.priorityclass.aspx)
[MSDN Link 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processpriorityclass.aspx)

Comment: If all you care about is being first, why bother?

Comment: Does this even cause it to use less than 100% CPU? Did you try it? I think any CPU bound thread will use up to 100% of CPU, all this does is cause it to yield to higher priority processes

Comment: If it yields it to higher priority processes, it means *this* process clearly isn't using 100% CPU. I strongly suspect this is what's wanted.

Comment: It will use 100% CPU if nothing else is running. But any process with normal priority will get all CPU resources. I use it in my applications and it is very unintrusive. BOINC (think SETI@home) uses the same technique.

Answer (score 6):

You can also introduce a slow Sleep into the main loop that's pegging the processor.

For example, this is often done by game loops - calling `Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1);` once per frame will take most games from using 100% cpu to using 1-2% cpu, and still allow reasonable access.

----- Edit ------

There are potential advantages of sleeping over lowering priority of the process or thread.  The main two are:

- Sleeping lets you have more control over how much processor time you give up.  If you lower your priority, and there are other CPU hungry processes, you may give up more processor time than you want.  [This is why I didn't do Sleep(0), either - since that won't always give up processor time, although it does give up some.  I've done this in embedded systems with longer sleeps to force less processor usage.]
- If your goal is to drop your total CPU usage, lowering your process priority won't help if nothing else is running.  You'll still eat 100% CPU.  This might potentially be useful if you're trying to keep your power draw down (save energy costs), or trying to keep your heat generation lower, depending on the architecture of your system.

----- From original -----

For other styles (UI) apps, another option is to refactor your routine to be asyncronous, break your processing into sections, and process it in blocks in a call by subscribing to something like Application.OnApplicationIdle.  This can allow your UI to stay somewhat responsive, since it'll run in spurts.

If this is a math routine, and it's doing a lot of computations, then reducing the thread priority and allowing it to use the most CPU available might be better.

Comment: Adding sleeps yields the processor even if there aren't other threads waiting. Thread/process priorities are a better way of doing this, IMO.

Comment: I agree. Please expand on why a slow Sleep would be good in this scenario.

Comment: Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(0) is my suggestion, that say : preempt cpu if necessary.

Comment: I expanded on why I suggested this.

Answer (score 4):

Since you said that you can't change the process priority, your only option is to insert artificial delays, as pointed out in a previous answer.  If you insert a Thread.Sleep(1) in your record loop, then at most you'll process 1,000 records per second.  If you want something more granular, then you'll have to insert a sleep every N records.

Comment: +1 for this one - I should've added that, too!  You'll also never process 1000 / second with a Thread.Sleep(1) - because Thread.Sleep(1) really sleeps for more like 14-15... Windows doesn't have the granularity to go in and out of a sleep that fast.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
thisProc.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;//Or ProcessPriorityClass.Idle
```

Answer (score 0):

IF the program is spending large times processing file data then you should consider [asynchronous IO](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/File-Stream/illustratesasynchronousIO.htm). Also you could split the program into multiple sections/ multiple threads that are scheduled with pauses between them

Comment: But the program isn't IO bound.  It's just taking too much processor time.  Using asynchronous IO won't change that.